# Basic application of fundamental galois theorem?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Let $E/F$ be a galois extension with group $S_n$. let $G$ be the stabilizer of $1$ and $H$ be generated by the cycle $(1,\dots ,n)$. I need to find $[E^GE^H:F],[E^G:F],[E^H:F],[E^G\cap E^H:F]$.

For $[E^G:F]$ I got $n$ by orbit stabilizer theorem. for $[E^H:F]$ I got $(n-1)!$ by using the tower rule and the fact the subgroup generated by the cycle has order $n$. how to get the other two though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will do the last one, hoping it is correct. Notice that $ m \in E^G \cap E^H$ if and only if $\sigma(m)=m$ and $\tau(m)=m$ for all $\sigma \in G$ and $\tau \in H$, if and only if $m \in E^{<G, H>}$. It is not too difficult to see $<G, H>= S_n$. So the desired degree is $1$.